# Fetching parameters in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a controller with a method i use for delete

```
destroy: function (req, res, next) {

}
```

My url looks like `http:localhost:1337/noder/delete/23`

23 is the id of a record in my table. I am wondering how i would fetch the current url within the controller and extract params from the url?.

Comment: Please add the route code too.

Comment: I thought that wouldn't be a problem since there is the blueprint Api.

Comment: Yes but what's the route you call? `app.get('noder/delete/:id')`?

Comment: This example https://github.com/irlnathan/activityoverlord/blob/master/config/routes.js  has no custom routes but manages to do this https://github.com/irlnathan/activityoverlord/commit/5286f32de9ec8843fa269c8087c19db80d7ba90e#diff-2892a201d1e423fac8a79de57a600f3aR96

Comment: So probably you get the id with `req.params.id`

Comment: Yes Michelem is correct I generally do var record = req.param('id') as long as id is the parameter you defined.